# Class of <- calls in R

Tags: r, class

This may be a simple question. But, why are these two classes different?

```
class(call("assign", "x", 2))
[1] "call"

class(call("<-", "x", 2))
[1] "<-"
```

Why is there a `<-` class for calls?

Comment: There are some other ones that confused me too. Like `class(body(mean.default))`.   It's definitely worth investigating all the S3 classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain that this behaviour is a hold-over from S and is not relevant for R.  You're exercising a relatively ill-defined part of the R language: what is the class of an object that does use S3 or S4?

We turn turn to the source code for answers:

```
class
#> function (x)  .Primitive("class")
pryr::show_c_source(.Primitive("class"))
#> class is implemented by R_do_data_class with op = 0
```

That leads us to [`R_do_data_class`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0c43709dfb69053b8669223db04a24b33d2b9724/src/main/attrib.c#L821) and then [`R_data_class`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0c43709dfb69053b8669223db04a24b33d2b9724/src/main/attrib.c#L608).  The object isn't S4, and doesn't have an class attribute, so it fails back to some defaults. In the case of LANGSXPs it calls [`lang2str`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0c43709dfb69053b8669223db04a24b33d2b9724/src/main/attrib.c#L578):

```
/* character elements corresponding to the syntactic types in the
   grammar */
static SEXP lang2str(SEXP obj, SEXPTYPE t)
{
  SEXP symb = CAR(obj);
  static SEXP if_sym = 0, while_sym, for_sym, eq_sym, gets_sym,
    lpar_sym, lbrace_sym, call_sym;
  if(!if_sym) {
    /* initialize:  another place for a hash table */
    if_sym = install("if");
    while_sym = install("while");
    for_sym = install("for");
    eq_sym = install("=");
    gets_sym = install("<-");
    lpar_sym = install("(");
    lbrace_sym = install("{");
    call_sym = install("call");
  }
  if(isSymbol(symb)) {
    if(symb == if_sym || symb == for_sym || symb == while_sym ||
       symb == lpar_sym || symb == lbrace_sym ||
       symb == eq_sym || symb == gets_sym)
      return PRINTNAME(symb);
  }
  return PRINTNAME(call_sym);
}
```

You can see that this function special cases a number of function calls with their own class.

I don't think these classes are currently used in the R source, but you could make use of them yourself:

```
f <- function(x) UseMethod("f")
f.if <- function(x) "If statement"
f.while <- function(x) "While loop"

x <- quote(if (a) TRUE)
f(x)
#> "If statement"

y <- quote(while(TRUE){})
f(y)
#> "While loop"
```

(Of course it would be a bad idea to actually do this because this is an extremely esoteric corner of the language and no one would understand how it works)